# Android studio 1.3 preview 2

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm having an issue where android studio doesn't render the preference UI due to the dependency exception, `Exception raised during rendering: Dependency "XXXX" not found for preference "XXXXX"` is there any workaround to work this out? or should we have to wait until the next release?

Comment: Release version has same problem...

Comment: Problem seems to still exist in 1.4 Beta 2. Have you filed a bug?

Comment: @Karuma nope i didn't. Im sick of firing bugs that they dont get fixed and if they get fixed, they broke other things. So i rather be quite lol

Comment: @k0sh totally agree. I had experiences like this with the latest support library. Anyways I made a bug report for the issue that you find here:
[link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185039)